# Best practice for making small changes in UI with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux and React to load data from a web service which is working well. I'd like to make small non-webservice-based changes in the UI in response to an action. A simplified example:

```js
class SmartComponent extends React.Component {
    handleClick = (e) => { 
         // how to best handle a simple state change here?
    }
    render() {
        const { displayMessage } = this.props
        return (
            <DumbComponent message={displayMessage}/>
            <button onclick={this.handleClick}>Change Message</button>)    
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    // state variables linked in the reducer
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SmartComponent)

let DumbComponent = ({ message }) => {
    return ({message})
}
```

If I modify the state in `SmartComponent`, for instance, by using `this.setState`, the props of `SmartComponent` will not be automatically updated. I believe it's a React anti-pattern to directly modify the props of `SmartComponent`. Is the best way to update the message in `DumbComponent` to make an action creator and link it in the reducer? That seems a bit overkill for a simple message change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should link it to the reducer.

However this is not mandatory:

**How to do it**

One other way to do this would be to store the message in the `state` of the SmartComponent.
Beware about the fact that Redux is no longer the single source of truth for the message.

```
class SmartComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // Initialize state based on props
        this.state = {
          message: props.message,
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // Handle state update on props (ie. store) update
        this.setState({ message: ... })
    }

    handleClick = (e) => { 
         this.setState({ message: ... })
    }

    render() {
        const { displayMessage } = this.state
        return (
            <DumbComponent message={displayMessage}/>
            <button onclick={this.handleClick}>Change Message</button>)    
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    // state variables linked in the reducer
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SmartComponent)
let DumbComponent = ({ message }) => {
    return ({message})
}
```

**Should you do it ?**

If the data you display in this component can be completely isolated from the rest of your application, that is to say no dispatched action could modify it, and no other component need it, keeping this data in the store can be unnecessary.

I mostly use this method to perform optimistic updates to the view component without altering the store until new value is saved by the server.